# Неправильное перенаправление на javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, url

С помощью `ajax` я отправляю запрос серверу. Сервер посылает мне `url` адресс (строку) на которую мне надо перейти с помощью `javascript`.
То есть я нахожусь на `http://example.com/en`. Отправил запрос и сервер вернул мне
`http://example.com/ru`. При использовании метода `window.location`, он перенаправляет меня не на ту страницу, то есть на `http://example.com/en/ru`, а мне надо на `http://example.com/ru`.

**Как решить эту проблему?**

**Возможно я использую неправильный метод для перенаправления или сервер посылает мне `url` адресс в неправильном формате**

Comment: ну так выведи то, что возвращает тебе сервер, и посмотри

Comment: сервер посылает правильный url. Вот только при методе window.location он перенаправляет в неправильное место. Он как-бы добавляет его в уже существующий url

Comment: ну вы еще скажите, что то, что присылает сервер начинается с `/`, то есть `/ru` а не просто `ru`, и вы именно в том виде его вписываете в location

Comment: @ruslan4742 не может этого быть

Comment: в любом случае, приведите код, как именно вы меняете URL, и приведите то, что возвращает вам сервер

Comment: @teran Я посылаю его вот таком виде http: //example.com/ru

Comment: `window.location.href = VALUE_FROM_SERVER`